# String masking with Regex at Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to mask name and surname in Oracle. 
For example; John Smith => Jo** Sm**

I can write a PL/SQL function. But i want to do this with regex. I can't write the right template. Is regex the right solution? Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: RegEx is almost ALWAYS the answer. In this case as well, ultimately, yes, you're going to be doing regex, probably using the regex_replace() function

Comment: be aware there is a security feature in the database ($) called Data Redaction, that allows you to create a policy where data is redacted (optionally with a regex) based on user privs...I can see your salary, but no one else can kind of thing

Comment: Would _all_ your names always consist of just a single first and last name?  Or could there two word first/last names and/or middle names too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want todo it with regexp you can use the following:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('John Smith', '(\w{2})\w+', '\1**')
```

Comment: This is a great solution